# Python - Speech Recognition: Attribute error : __enter__

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am trying to code jarvis in python using speech recognition and pyttsx3 modules. I got stuck due to an error which says `Attribute error:__enter__`
I don't understand why it is showing so. I am new to python. Currently I am using python 3.8.

```
def takeCommmand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone as source:
        print("listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1  
        audio = r.listen(source)
        return
```

Error:

```
File "c:/Users/Dell/Desktop/jarvis voice assistant/jarvis.py", line 28, in takeCommmand
with sr.Microphone as source:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Please tell me whats wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def takeCommmand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source: # <--- look here
        print("listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1  
        audio = r.listen(source)
        return
```

You need to add the `()` for it to work.